# How to connect to mturk sandbox with boto3

Tags: boto3, mechanicalturk

How to specify the mTurk sandbox host.  In boto this was done with connection, but I don't see that in the boto3 API.

this is boto

```
connection = MTurkConnection(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                         aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                         host='mechanicalturk.sandbox.amazonaws.com')
```

from [scottlobdell](http://scottlobdell.me/2015/03/use-mechanical-turk-python-boto-crowdsource-tasks/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i figured it out

```
endpoint_url = 'https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

# Uncomment this line to use in production
# endpoint_url = 'https://mturk-requester.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

client = boto3.client('mturk',
    endpoint_url = endpoint_url
)
```